# How to map (relate) two unrelated tables without adding any column in sql and powerbi

Tags: sql, powerbi

I have 2 tables named A1 and B1. And both the tables has commonly 3 columns but in different variable. Considering A1 as the master table I have to map B1 but the values in A1 (those particular ID's(3 columns)) will not be present in B1 and vice versa. And the ID's present in both table contains duplicates. I have to find the relationship (map) the two tables without adding any extra attribute in SQL and POWERBI

Here is the sample table:
[image: Here is the sample table.]

Comment: You can use join on row number.

Comment: I don't completely follow your question.  It would help if you could include the sample data in your question directly as _text_, formatted with four or more spaces on each line.  And also show the expected output from the query you want.

Comment: Not clear from this how you want to join or union the tables. Your use of terms *variable* and *3 columns* is not clear what you are referring to. If you can give the sample data actually inside your question (not an image, just include it with 4 spaces at start of line and it will format ok), and also the desired result set then we can probably answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Copy the ID from A1 table to a new table. (Use 'Add as new query' option)
2. Merge the ID from B1 table to the new column you just created.
3. Right click and remove duplicates from the new column. Now you have a master ID column without any duplicate values.
4. Map this column with ID in A1 and B1.